# Как парсить html в java?

Tags: java, html, парсер

Нужно пропарсить вебстраницу и извлечь из нее путь к картинке. Никак не могу разобраться с классом  [HTML Parser](http://htmlparser.sourceforge.net/). Нужен пример - не могу найти в нете.

Comment: Или может быть другие есть классы более удобные?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

А что сложного то?

У них самая обыкновенная документация в JavaDoc. Но даже там можно найти почти все, что нужно. 
[Например](http://htmlparser.sourceforge.net/javadoc/org/htmlparser/Parser.html#main(java.lang.String[])):

> Typical usage of the parser is:
>
> ```
> Parser parser = new Parser ("http://whatever");
> NodeList list = parser.parse (null);
> // do something with your list of nodes.
> ```

А потом еще немного посмотреть:

```
NodeList parse(NodeFilter filter)
```

`NodeFilter` -> [вот тут](http://htmlparser.sourceforge.net/javadoc/org/htmlparser/NodeFilter.html)

Все, по-моему, слишком просто.

Не говоря уже об этом

> bin/parser http://website_url
>   [tag_name]
>       where tag_name is an optional tag name to be used as a filter, i.e.
>           A - Show only the link tags extracted from the document
>           IMG - Show only the image tags extracted from the document
>           TITLE - Extract the title from the document
>       NOTE: this is also the default program for the htmlparser.jar, so the
>   above could be:
>       java -jar lib/htmlparser.jar http://website_url [tag_name]

**UPD:**

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    try {
        Parser parser = new Parser("http://www.alliance-bags.ru/catalog.php?tov=576");
        parser.setEncoding("windows-1251");

        NodeFilter atrb1 = new TagNameFilter("IMG");
        NodeList nodeList = parser.parse(atrb1);

        for(int i=0; i<nodeList.size(); i++) {
            Node node = nodeList.elementAt(i);
            System.out.println(node.toHtml());
        }

    } catch (ParserException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

Comment: спасибо попробую отпишусь как получится.
http://jericho.htmlparser.net/docs/index.html\
еще один парсер нашел.

Comment: Зря, и этот, проверил, работает замечательно:)

Comment: Все равно не разобрался в синтаксисе. не можешь показать на примере как извлечь путь к картинке в http://www.alliance-bags.ru/catalog.php?tov=576 через htmlparser.sourceforge.net
Заранее спасибо

Comment: Смотрите UPD, выводятся все найденные ноды IMG. А там уже выбирайте. *Пример работает, но не заслуживает быть примером хорошего стиля программирования.*

Answer (score 3):

Попробуйте [jsoup](http://tdlite.ru/java/jsoup-parser-html-java/). Мне очень понравился.

Answer (score 2):

Для простых случаев можно воспользоваться стандартным API Java. Например, достать файл через [HttpURLConnection](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/net/HttpURLConnection.html) и найти необходимое с помощью [регулярных выражений](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/regex/package-summary.html).

Answer (score 2):

[jsoup: Java HTML Parser](http://jsoup.org/):

```
Document doc = Jsoup.connect("http://en.wikipedia.org/").get();
Elements newsHeadlines = doc.select("#mp-itn b a");
```

Answer (score 0):

Можно использовать стандартные для Java инструменты. Зачем для извлечения пути к картинке использовать дополнительную либу?

Если необходимо единоразово сделать, то можно использовать DOM и XPath.
Если же необходимо обработать кучу больших документов, то лучше использовать SAX. Единожды потратив время на разбор этих методов больше  никогда не будете знать проблем с разбором не только HTML, но и любых XML документов.

Использование же регулярных выражений для разбора HTML не есть хорошая практика - просто в силу особенности гибкости и необязательности синтаксиса HTML.

Comment: Как раз особенной гибкости и необязательности синтаксиса HTML нельзя использовать DOM и XPath. Даже SAX.

Answer (score 0):

Посмотрите на [этот](http://htmlparser.sourceforge.net/). Довольно простой принцип работы, поддерживает невалидные страницы. Есть коллекция объектов, замапленых на теги. Очень удобно. 
Если есть вопросы - спрашивайте.